# Segmentation Fault using a function pointer with array argument

Tags: arrays, c, function-pointers, implicit-conversion, function-declaration

today i started learning C, and i got stucked in function pointers. This is my code:

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sumOfElements(int *arr, int arr_elements);

int main()
{

    int (*ptr)(int,int) = NULL;
    ptr = sumOfElements;
    int a[] = {128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1};
    printf("Total of price is: %d", ptr(a, 8));

}

int sumOfElements(int *arr, int arr_elements)
{
    int k =0;
    int total;
    for(;k < arr_elements;k++)
    {
        total += arr[k];
    }
    return total;
}
```

What i'm trying to do is access the elements of the array in the `sumOfElements` functions. When i call it normally, then everything goes smooth. When i try to use the `function pointer`, then the compiler throw me some warning before, and then the `Segmentation Fault` error:

```
main.c:17:9: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]                               
main.c:19:41: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘ptr’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]              
main.c:19:41: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘int *’    
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Since i'm still learning it, i'm unsure about touching the code, because, like i said before, it works without the `function pointer`. Now, the error `main.c:17:9: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]`, i didn't really understand it, because they're both `int`. So, if you could explain that too, it would save me a lot of time. So, why does it only throw `Segmentation Fault (core dumped)` when i use the `funptr`? All i know is that the Segmentation error is when we try to access memory that is only `read-only` or it's `out-of-bound`

Comment: `int total;` is Uninitialized leading to *Undefined Behavior* when used with `total += arr[k];` set `int total = 0;`

Comment: Save time: Enable all warnings - faster feedback than posting  on SO.

Answer (score 5):

For starters the pointer is declared like

```
int (*ptr)(int,int) = NULL;
```

that is it is a pointer to a function with two parameters of the type `int`.

But the function `sumOfElements` have different types of parameters

```
int sumOfElements(int *arr, int arr_elements);
```

That is the first parameter has the type `int *` instead of `int`.

Also as the array is not changed within the function then it is better to declare the function like

```
long long int sumOfElements( const int *arr, size_t arr_elements);
```

The function return type is `long long int` instead of `int` because it decreases the risk of overflow of the sum of elements of the array.

Correspondingly the pointer shall be declared like

```
long long int (*ptr)( const int *, size_t ) = NULL;
```

and the function should be called like

```
printf("Total of price is: %lld", ptr(a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) ) );
```

Within the function you forgot to initialize the variable `total`.

```
int total;
```

The function can be defined the following way

```
long long int sumOfElements( const int *arr, size_t arr_elements )
{
    long long int total = 0;

    while( arr_elements-- )
    {
        total += arr[arr_elements];
    }

    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function pointer declaration is of incorrect type.

Your pointer has signature of `int (*ptr)(int,int) = NULL;` while your function is `int ()(int *, int)`.

Try declaring your pointer as `int (*ptr)(int *,int) = NULL;`

Answer (score 1):

The function pointer needs to have the same parameter and return types as the function itself. In your `ptr` declaration you declare the first argument as `int`, but it should be `int*`.

```
    int (*ptr)(int*,int) = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `int (*ptr)(int*,int) = NULL;` instead of `int (*ptr)(int,int) = NULL;`, since your array is an int pointer.
As your regular function sumOfElements already receives an int pointer it works correctly.